# JBoss 6.3 EAP - define other simple namaing bindings in domain for evey server

Tags: binding, jboss, naming

we need to define a different file url via simple naming bindings for every server in a JBoss domain.

e.g. we need for every server in the cluster an entry like

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.4">
            <bindings>
                <simple name="java:/url/ServerConfigurationUrl" value="file:///c:/JBoss//server3.properties" type="java.net.URL"/>
            </bindings>
        </subsystem>
```

Can this be achieved using some variables? Expressions seem not to be valid here.

If we could just use something like value=${path to file} that would be great.

Thanks,
ralf

Answer (score 0):

Using something like

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="FILEURL" value=value="file:///c:/JBoss//server3.properties" />
</system-properties>
```

and then

```
<bindings>
   <simple name="java:/url/ServerConfigurationUrl" value="${FILEURL}" type="java.net.URL"/>
</bindings>
```

worked for me.

Greetings,
ralf